# Downloading HTML form as PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a simple html form. I want to download the data that i filled in the form as PDF file.

What is the most simple solution?

```
<label for="fname">Adı</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Adınız">

<label for="lname">Soyadı</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Soyadınız">

<label for="country">Konu</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="australia">İade/Değişim</option>
  <option value="canada">Ödeme Problemleri</option>
  <option value="usa">Defolu Ürün</option>
</select>

<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Buraya sorunuzu açıklayın..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Gönder">
```

Comment: You can try jspdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a library like https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js

Comment: Thanks, but how do i send all form data to function? var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
html2pdf(element);

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. html2pdf
2. puppeteer

both are additional `Javascript` libraries you can use to do this... but `puppeteer` also requires `node`.

See more here: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/html-to-pdf-in-javascript/